# Using "find" non-recursively?

Tags: shell, find

Using `/bin/find /root -name '*.csv'` returns:

```
/root/small_devices.csv
/root/locating/located_201606291341.csv
/root/locating/located_201606301411.csv
/root/locating/g_cache.csv
/root/locating/located_201606291747.csv
/root/locating/located_201607031511.csv
/root/locating/located_201606291746.csv
/root/locating/located_201607031510.csv
/root/locating/located_201606301412.csv
/root/locating/located_201606301415.csv
/root/locating/located_201607031512.csv
```

I don't actually want all the files under `/root/locating/`, so the expected output is simply `/root/small_devices.csv`.

Is there an efficient way of using `find' non-recursively?

I'm using CentOS if it matters.

Comment: Why can't you just do something like `echo /root/*.csv` ?

Comment: @StephenHarris Primarily because I didn't think of that :)

Comment: Or try `ls -d1 /root/*.csv`.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

You can do that with `-maxdepth` option:

```
/bin/find /root -maxdepth 1 -name '*.csv'
```

As mentioned in the comments, add `-mindepth 1` to exclude starting points from the output. From `man find`:

> **-maxdepth levels**
>
> Descend  at  most  levels  (a  non-negative  integer)  levels of directories below the starting-points. `-maxdepth 0` means only apply the tests and actions to the starting-points themselves.
>
> **-mindepth levels**
>
> Do  not  apply  any  tests or actions at levels less than levels (a non-negative integer).
> `-mindepth 1` means process all files  except the starting-points.

Comment: You may sometimes want to also specify `-mindepth 1`. For example, `find /csv -maxdepth 1 -name '*csv'` includes `/csv` (which has a depth of 0) in its output, whereas `find /csv -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -name '*csv'` does not.

Answer (score 14):

With standard `find`:

```
find /root ! -path /root -prune -type f -name '*.csv'
```

This will prune (remove) all directories in `/root` from the search, except for the `/root` directory itself, and continue with printing the filenames of any regular file that matches `*.csv`.

With GNU `find` (and any other `find` implementation that understands `-maxdepth`):

```
find /root -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.csv'
```

---

If you only want to prune the path `/root/locating`:

```
find /root -path /root/locating -prune -o -type f -name '*.csv' -print
```

Now, all subdirectories under `/root` are entered, except for the specific subdirectory `/root/locating`.

Note that you can't do this with the `-maxdepth` option.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `-maxdepth` and `-mindepth` primaries:

```sh
find /root -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -name '*.csv'
```

With [FreeBSD `find`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?find(1)) (used by macOS) you might be tempted to use `-depth 1` instead of `-maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1`, but that would be inefficient, since as [Stéphane Chazelas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22565) [comments below](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/298590/using-find-non-recursively#comment1332700_612029),`depth 1` "doesn't stop `find` from descending into directories of depth greater than 1", as does `-maxdepth 1`. [GNU `find`](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/) doesn't support `-depth n`.

Comment: Note that it's specific to the FreeBSD implementation of `find` (also found on macOS I believe).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, thank you. I just updated my answer.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, `-depth 1` is not equivalent  to `-mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1` as it doesn't stop `find` from descending into directories of depth greater than 1. It's only a test for the current depth.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, it's all good. Thank you. I just updated my answer.