# How to sum the number of JSON elements in documents inside a directory using jq

Tags: jq

I have around **3K** JSON files inside a directory and each file contains approximately 250 **(+/-)** JSON elements inside it, I want to count the total number of JSON elements from those files as a sum.

Currently using `jq` like below command which returns numbers in each line but I want to count total by adding them,

```
jq length *.json
```

**Current Output**,

```
250
248
250
240
...
...
250
```

**Expected Output** (approx),

```
600530
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using `jq` only:

```
jq -s 'map(length) | add' ./*.json
```

`-s`/`--slurp` makes `jq` read its input as a single array, running the specified filter only once against it. `map` is used to run `length` for each element of that virtual array, returning an array of numbers, and `add` finally sums them.

To also make sure not to hit the command line length limit (but note that this would also recursively process files in subdirectories<sup>1</sup>):

```
find . -name "*.json" -exec jq 'length' {} + | jq -s 'add'
```

Found files are passed to `jq 'length'` in batches whose size depends on the maximum command line length allowed on your system. Since `find` may run `jq` more than once, making it slurp its input won't reliably work and its output is piped to a second (slurping) `jq` instead.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Several Q/As on this site show how to prevent `find` from descending into directories; for instance, [Using "find" non-recursively?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/298590/315749)</sub>

Answer (score 2):

You can use simple `awk` command i.e.

```
jq length ./*.json | awk '{sum=sum+$0} END{print sum}'
```